# Could we have the option to automatically show new questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

So, if we plan on having a specific tab open for a while. Could we have an option to `Automatically display new questions?` built into the website rather than having to click on the message.

[image]

This option could possibly be placed under the `Site Settings -> Preferences tab`. We could even have it working only for specific tags chosen by the user. Here is a picture example of what I mean.

[image]

Comment: It should be pretty simple to do that with a userscript.

Comment: It is in fact at once dead-simple to implement this, and rather challenging. See, elsewhere on SE this just happens, no options or userscript necessary. The code is *already there*. But on SO, it's not performant to do this for the homepage, because there's such a ridiculous firehose of questions, so it was deliberately disabled. Instead, you have to filter substantially in some fashion, such as by going to a tag page, before you can get live updates.